# RxJava - Can I Bypass onSuccess and only have an onError option?

Tags: rx-java, observable, subscribe, disposable

I am creating a `Disposable`:

```
myDisposable = myObservableMethod().subscribe(this::mySuccess, this::myError);
```

In this case, if `myObservableMethod()` returns a success, there is nothing more that I need to do, so `mySuccess()` is and empty method and exists for no reason.

I have tried this:

```
myDisposable = myObservableMethod().doOnError(this::myError).subscribe();
```

but am getting crashes.

Is there anyway to call this without needing an `onSuccess` ?

Comment: Use a static empty consumer instance: `public static final Consumer<Object> emptyConsumer = o -> { };` so you don't need to define empty methods/lambdas all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have crash because you don't handle the error, exception is thrown to the upper level and crashes with unhandling exception.

You could place empty lambda in place

```
... subscribe(ignore -> {}, this::myError)
```